# Map path to App_Data with HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()

Tags: c#, wpf, path, httpcontext

I am writing a small WPF application that will use word templates and merge them with data. The issue is that I am trying to avoid using the absolute path to the App_Data folder in my Visual Studio C# project for obvious reasons. I'm trying to map the path to the App_Data folder so I can use a template from there. However it is giving me the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null.
```

Here are is my code:

```
String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data");
path = path + "/Acknowledgement_Letter.dotx";
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use ~ before your path

string Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");

Comment: App_data folder has permission. 
Please test on another folders of your project.